# Using MinValue with NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, function-construction, mathematical-optimization, evaluation

A simplified example looks like this. The basic idea is to maximize `fHelper` by adjusting `\[Alpha]` for each `t`, and then use the resulting `f` in a differential equation. In the real world application, however, the functions and differential equation are much more complicated.

```
fHelper[t_, u_] := t + u;
f[t_] := MinValue[{fHelper[t, u], u >= 0.15, u <= 1.5}, u];
solution = NDSolve[{g'[t] == f[t], g[0.03] == 0}, g, {t, 0, 0.03}];
```

The last line produces a series of errors, which seems to be related to unsuccessful evaluation of `f`.

```
NMinimize::nnum:
   The function value 0.211738 + t is not a number at {u} = {0.211738}.

NMinimize::nnum:
   The function value 0.211738 + t is not a number at {u} = {0.211738}.

NMinimize::nnum:
   The function value 0.211738 + t is not a number at {u} = {0.211738}.

General::stop: Further output of NMinimize::nnum
     will be suppressed during this calculation.
```

I have checked `f` to see if there is something wrong with it, but it behaves exactly like a normal pure function, and I have no idea why Mathematica is complaining.

```
In[4]:= f[0.01]

Out[4]= 0.16

In[5]:= f[0.02]

Out[5]= 0.17
```

Comment: Use `f[t_?NumericQ]:=...` for function `f` definition.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/26037#26037, esp. [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/26037#26037)

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
fHelper[t_, u_] := t + u;
f[t_] := MinValue[{fHelper[t, u], u >= 0.15, u <= 1.5}, u];
int = {#, f @@ #} & /@ Range[0, 0.03, 0.001] // Interpolation;
solution = g/.Flatten@NDSolve[{g'[t] == int[t], g[0.03] == 0}, g, {t, 0, 0.03}];
Plot[solution[t],{t,0,0.03}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

```
fHelper[t_, u_] := t + u;
f[t_?NumericQ] := MinValue[{fHelper[t, u], u >= 0.15, u <= 1.5}, u];
solution = NDSolveValue[{g'[t] == f[t], g[0.03] == 0}, g, {t, 0, 0.03}];
Plot[solution[x], {x, 0, 0.03}]
```

[image]